# SharePoint 2010: show hidden columns with WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I create a list, add 2 columns and insert 2 items via c# Webservice. In SharePoint I cannot see the 2 columns, only Title. When I edit the items, I see the other columns. In SharePoint I can change the view to see the 2 columns. But how to change the view with Webservice?

I try this:

```
    private void SetView(string listName, string viewName, String[] arr)
    {
        AllViews.Views viewService = new AllViews.Views();
        viewService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        //from msdn
        //string strQuery1 = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
        //   "<Value Type=\"Title\"></Value>" + "</Gt></Where>" +
        //   "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></OrderBy>";

        string strQuery = "<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
            "</IsNotNull></Where></Query>";

        string strRowLimit = "150";

        string strViewFields = "";

        int count = arr.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            strViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\'" + arr[i] + "\'/>";
        }

        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

        System.Xml.XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
        System.Xml.XmlNode ndRowLimit = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "RowLimit", "");
        System.Xml.XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");

        ndQuery.InnerXml = strQuery;
        ndRowLimit.InnerXml = strRowLimit;
        ndViewFields.InnerXml = strViewFields;

        XmlNode retNode = viewService.AddView(listName, viewName, ndViewFields, ndQuery, ndRowLimit, "HTML", false)

    }
```

All without error, but columns hidden in the list. Maybe the query is wrong. Or the way that I use. Any tipps for me? Searching results are all about the SharePoint.dll, but I need a way with Webservice.

Comment: Strange. Open the list, try to get the view, get an error (try it later again), open the view, only click on OK, all columns visible. Whats wrog?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Change strQuery to:

```
string strQuery = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
            "</IsNotNull></Where>"; 
// is in Node ndQuery, dont need it again. Maybe a dirty trick to hide new Columns
```

Set the new View as default with UpdateView. Be sure to use the GUID from the view.

For viewProperties **only the prop that you want to change**

```
string strProp = "DefaultView =\"TRUE\"";
```

All works fine. Have a nice weekend.